# Why is a computer on my network not resolving correctly?

Tags: active-directory, dhcp, windows, dhcp-server

I am running Windows 2003 Server with Active Directory and DHCP enabled.

the machine: laptop1 receives the IP: 10.2.6.134 from the Windows 2003 DHCP Server.

the machine name and IP does not show up when I check the DHCP scope on the server.

when I ping laptop1 from the server it resolves the IP: 10.2.6.129

I have used the ipconfig /flushdns and it did not resolve the issue

When I run the command ping -a 10.2.6.134 it resolves the correct hostname.

Any ideas on what I can try/check or what may be causing the issue here. I have exhausted all of my resources. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a DNS problem than a DHCP problem... Did you check your DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a superfluous entry for laptop1 in your DNS server. Remove it manually. There may also be something coming from WINS.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging laptop1 using its full name (including the domain name of the AD in which it lives). For example, ping laptop.someADdomain.lcl. Do you get the same results?

If this works correctly, DNS is probably OK and the name resolution is coming from somewhere else (such as WINS).

If laptop1 is a Windows machine, you can try the command (from an elevated command shell)

ipconfig /registerdns